# any links to work on postgres db partitioning

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I am doing Postgres partitioning work I went through the original forum site. Still i am having little confusion on that can anyone give me a better link or book to go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation below by postgresql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Hope it will help you

Answer (score -1):

You may try to check out some of those links:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106014/how-to-partition-existing-table-in-postgres
- https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/scaling-postgresql-performance-table-partitioning
- https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2016-09-13-handling-very-large-tables-in-postgres-using-partitioning/
- https://blog.akquinet.de/2014/04/09/postgresql-partitioning-big-tables-part-2/